# how to check a username doesn't already exist in a table?

Tags: python, mysql, database, validation

I am coding a program which takes a user input as the username and then queries the database to check the username has not already been used. This is the code I have come up with so far but the problem is it always returns 'None' as a response to the query even if the username does exist in the table.

```
mycursor= mydb.cursor()
username=input('username')
checkUsername= mycursor.execute('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = %(username)s', {'username' :username})
print (checkUsername)
```

Comment: You have to fetch the result. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html

Answer (score 1):

When you execute, you just tell the cursor to communicate the statement on the DB. It returns None but what it does is allow your cursor to be in a state where you can fetch results.

```py
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
username = input('username')
checkUsername = mycursor.execute('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = %(username)s', {'username' :username})

row = cursor.fetchone()

username_exists = row is not None
```

Comment: Note: you can also use `fetchall()` instead of `fetchone()` for when your query may return more than one result. Or `fetchmany(size=50)` to fetch a specified number of results (e.g. 50). Class documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor.html